# Issue installing celery in Django

Tags: django, celery

This is my django settings file where i am tryin to  configure celery from this link [here](http://www.apreche.net/complete-single-server-django-stack-tutorial/) but i get this error as the following,what am i doing wrong here,

This the command where this error is being thrown

`python manage.py celeryd`

`raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
Improperly Configured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured`

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
},
'db1': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'hp',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'php123',
    'PORT': '3306'
    }
}

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'djcelery',
 )

BROKER_URL = "django://hp:hp@localhost:5672/<RABBIT_VHOST>"
#CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database"

#choose the setting that matches your database of choice
CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = "mysql://root:php123@localhost/celery_db"

INSTALLED_APPS += ('kombu.transport.django', )

#put these two lines at the very bottom of the settings file
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

Comment: Weird... I recreated the error. It seems to work find if `default` is not intentionally left empty. Maybe open a GitHub issue if SO doesn't work out?